# Passing STATIC_URL to file javascript with django

Tags: javascript, python, django, static

Which is the best solution to pass {{ STATIC_URL }} to javascript files?

I'm working with django and python.

Thanks in advance.
Regards.

Comment: Are you mean load javascript files to a template? or you mean use the {{ STATIC_URL }}'s value in the javascript file?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`django-compressor` lets you do this as well as optimize your site by condensing all of your required JS or CSS into one file and optimizing file size.

**UPDATE:** By default, compressor will convert relative urls into absolute urls using `STATIC_URL`. If you download the development version, it comes with a django template engine parser which lets you use all django template code directly in your CSS files, such as the `{% static %}` tag.

https://github.com/jezdez/django_compressor

Enable the `TemplateFilter` in settings.py after installing to parse your js or css files via the template engine.

```
COMPRESS_JS_FILTERS = [
    'compressor.filters.template.TemplateFilter',
]
```

Now any JS within `{% compress js %}` blocks will be parsed by the django template language...

```
{% compress js %}
    <script src="/my_script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
{% endcompress %}

// my_script.js
alert('{{ STATIC_URL|escapejs }}');
```

You asked for the best way -- I think this is the best. Certainly better than serving dynamic files.

Comment: This is a terrific suggestion! django-compressor is a cool project.

Comment: @slypete, yes it's amazing! Optimize file count, file size, and even add template variables. Brilliant. This is my latest huge django game changer.. what's next!?

Comment: I'm really liking this tool - one note is to install it using 'pip install django_compressor' rather than cloning it from github - took less that 10 minutes to set up. Only issue I had was to explicitly set 'COMPRESS_ENABLED = True' in my settings.py... as if you already have DEBUG = True from some other application, it will read that and not actually compress.

Comment: I've setup all the options, and the files are concatenated and compressed.The problem is that as soon as I add `COMPRESS_JS_FILTERS` to get this code working in JS files: `{{ STATIC_URL|escapejs }}` then the files are concatenated but **not compressed** anymore. What am I missing?

Answer (score 38):

Using a global javascript variable with the static url value is more simple :

```
<script language="javascript">var STATIC_URL = "{{ STATIC_URL|escapejs }}";</script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/myfile.js"></script>
```

Then, you can simply use the static url by calling STATIC_URL in myfile.js :

```
html = '<img src="'+STATIC_URL+'/icons/flags/tn.gif">';
```

Answer (score 5):

**I think this complements the commentary of  @Yuji 'Tomita' Tomita, as a full setup.**

this worked for me.

This is how i did the full setup of django compressor for using STATIC_URL in django js file.

https://github.com/jezdez/django_compressor

```
pip install django_compressor
```

Add 'compressor' to your INSTALLED_APPS setting:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    # other apps
    "compressor",
)
```

To test compression in Debug mode, in settings.py:

```
COMPRESS_ENABLED = True
```

In case you use Django’s staticfiles contrib app (or its standalone counterpart django-staticfiles) you have to add Django Compressor’s file finder to the STATICFILES_FINDERS setting, for example with django.contrib.staticfiles:

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    # other finders..
    'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder',
)
```

Enable the TemplateFilter in settings.py after installing to parse your js or css files via the template engine.

```
COMPRESS_JS_FILTERS = [
    'compressor.filters.template.TemplateFilter',
]
```

Now any JS within {% compress js %} blocks will be parsed by the django template language...

```
{% load compress %}

{% compress js %}
    <script src="/my_script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
{% endcompress %}

// my_script.js

alert('{{ STATIC_URL|escapejs }}');
```

Comment: I was reading the docs and I didn't find this "STATICFILES_FINDERS" setting there. After I read your comment and added it, my app started working. Thanks!