# Use Django Template Tags in JavaScript File

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I was wondering if I could use the [template tag static](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#static) in my javascript file to call a CSV file I want to pass to D3 like so:

```
{% static "js/data.csv" %}
```

I'd really like my JavaScript files to be separate from my HTML, because it can get long and messy. Thanks for any help.

Comment: no because they are static resource files. A simple script tag variable could be used though in main page

Comment: Thats what i was hoping to avoid, because a D3 graphs can get real messy real fast.

Comment: was thinking you were just passing a url value ( I don't do django)...make ajax request and initialize graph in callback

Answer (score 1):

Use [django-compressor](https://github.com/jezdez/django_compressor)

> django-compressor lets you do this as well as optimize your site by
>   condensing all of your required JS or CSS into one file and optimizing
>   file size.
>
> UPDATE: By default, compressor will convert relative urls into
>   absolute urls using STATIC_URL. If you download the development
>   version, it comes with a django template engine parser which lets you
>   use all django template code directly in your CSS files, such as the
>   {% static %} tag.
>   by **Yuji 'Tomita' Tomita**

Read this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9576675/passing-static-url-to-file-javascript-with-django).